# Neo4J merge/union tables returned from same query but different nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So I have a query along the lines of `MATCH (g:Gene)-[r]-() RETURN DISTINCT type(r), count(r)` which returns a breakdown table of the number of in/out-going edges from a gene node, per relationship type.

I want to do this on a number of nodes and instead of doing it one table at a time, it would be awesome to just return a table with relationship types in one column and counts per gene on the subsequent ones.

```
MATCH (g:Gene {name: "G1"})-[r]-(n)
RETURN DISTINCT type(r),  count(r) as g1
UNION ALL MATCH (g:Gene {name: "G2"})-[r]-(n)
RETURN DISTINCT type(r),  count(r) as g2
```

Doesn't work due to syntax error: `All sub queries in an UNION must have the same column names (line 3, column 1 (offset: 108))`. This is likely due to the fact that some genes don't have all the relationship types that others have.

If I do the following:

```
MATCH (g:Gene {name: "G1"})-[r]-(n)
RETURN DISTINCT type(r), null as g2, count(r) as g1
UNION ALL MATCH (g:Gene {name: "G2"})-[r]-(n)
RETURN DISTINCT type(r), null as g1, count(r) as g2
```

then I get duplicate rows for relationship types, where it's null for g1 in one and for g2 in the other.

What am I misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 0):

The UNION error is because the columns do not match- changing it to

```
MATCH (g:Gene {name: "G1"})-[r]-(n)
RETURN DISTINCT type(r) as type,  count(r) as count
UNION ALL 
MATCH (g:Gene {name: "G2"})-[r]-(n)
RETURN DISTINCT type(r) as type ,  count(r) as count
```

will work.

Comment: This returns a single column with count, whereas I am looking to get count1, count2

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UNWIND](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/unwind/). and you need to return the node (g in here).

```
UNWIND ["G1", "G2"] AS name
MATCH (g:Gene {name: name})-[r]-(n) 
RETURN g , DISTINCT type(r) as type,  count(r) as count
```

Comment: This also returns a single count column, instead of summing the counts like the other answer it concatenates the two desired tables in length instead of width.